# Matrix representation of squeezing operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematics, quantum-optics, matrix-elements

In quantum mechanics we know that every operator can be represented by a matrix.Being a beginner of quantum optics, my question is does there exist a matrix for [squeezing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_operator) also? If does, can the elements of the matrix be parameterized?

Comment: "In quantum mechanics we know that every operator can be represented by a matrix" this in general only holds for (everywhere defined) bounded linear operators.

Comment: You need to choose a basis in order to parametrize a matrix representation. Which basis do you want to consider ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm following here the work of

> Ui, H. (1970). Clebsch-Gordan formulas of the SU (1, 1) group. *Progress of Theoretical Physics*, *44*(3), 689-702.

The squeezing operator $e^{-\frac12 \beta (a^\dagger a^\dagger-a a)}$ with $\beta\in \mathbb{R}$ transforms the initial harmonic oscillator operator into new ones:
$$
e^{-\frac12 \beta (a^\dagger a^\dagger-a a)}\left(\begin{array}{c}
a^\dagger \\ a\end{array}\right)e^{\frac12 \beta (a^\dagger a^\dagger-a a)}=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
b^\dagger \\ b\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cosh\frac\beta2&\sinh\frac\beta2\\
\sinh\frac\beta2&\cosh\frac\beta2\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
a^\dagger \\ a\end{array}\right)\, .
$$
This isn't quite the form you want, which has $z\in \mathbb{C}$, but the transformation $e^{-\frac\beta2(a^\dagger a^\dagger-aa)}$ has "easy" matrix elements between harmonic oscillator states.

Because the commutation relations of $\frac12 a^\dagger a^\dagger$, $\frac12 aa$ and $\frac12(a^\dagger a+\frac12)$ are "very similar" to those of angular momentum, it is possible to obtain the matrix elements by analogy with the rotation operator $e^{-i\beta J_y}$.  The result is in terms of the d-functions for the SU(1,1) group [rather than for $SU_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix) .

The general result, valid for $\cal M'\ge \cal M$, is
\begin{align}
&\langle{\cal J}{\cal M'}\vert e^{-\frac\beta2(a^\dagger a^\dagger-aa)} 
\vert {\cal J}{\cal M}\rangle \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\Gamma({\cal M'}+{\cal J})\Gamma({\cal M'}-{\cal J}+1)}{\Gamma({\cal M}+{\cal J})\Gamma({\cal M}-{\cal J}+1)}}
\left(\cosh\textstyle\frac\beta2\right)^{-\cal M-\cal M'}
\left(\sinh\textstyle\frac\beta2\right)^{\cal M'-\cal M}
P^{(\cal M'-\cal M,-\cal M-\cal M')}_{\cal M-\cal J}\left(\cosh\textstyle\frac\beta2\right)
\end{align}
where $P^{a,b}_c$ is a Jacobi polynomial.  For $\cal M'<\cal M$, one uses $d^{\cal J}_{\cal M'\cal M}(\beta)=(-1)^{\cal M-\cal M'}d^{\cal J}_{\cal M\cal M'}(\beta)$. I will leave it to you to read the paper for other specifics but:

- For the 1-particle even harmonic oscillator states, $\cal J=\frac14$ and the value of ${\cal M}$ is related to $n$ by $\cal M=\frac12(n+\frac12)$ so that $\vert n\rangle\mapsto \vert \cal J\cal M\rangle$ where, for instance, $\vert 0\rangle\mapsto 
  \vert \frac14\frac14\rangle$, $\vert 2\rangle\mapsto \vert\frac14\frac54\rangle$ etc.
- For the 1-particle odd harmonic oscillator states, $\cal J=\frac33$ and $\cal M=\frac12(n+\frac12)$ so that $\vert 3\rangle\mapsto\vert\frac34,\frac74\rangle$.

The specialized expression for $\cal J=\frac14$ and $\frac34$ are given in

> Ui, H. (1970). Boson Bogolyubov Transformation and the SU (1, 1) Group. Progress of Theoretical Physics, 44(3), 703-710

and in other papers as well but I know Ui better.

In general, a transformation of the type you have can be written in the form
$$
e^{-\frac12(z^* a^2-za^{\dagger 2})}
=e^{-i \alpha K_z} e^{-i\beta K_y}e^{i\alpha K_z}
$$
where
$$
K_z=\textstyle\frac12(a^\dagger a+\frac12)\, ,\qquad 
K_y=\frac{1}{2i}(a^{\dagger 2}-a^2)
$$
and you can easily find the connecting between $z, z^*$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  The operator
$$
e^{-i \alpha K_z}\vert \cal J,\cal M\rangle = e^{-i\alpha \cal M}\vert \cal J,\cal M\rangle
$$
so the general expression you are looking for is of the form
(phase for
$\langle \cal J\cal M'\vert \times d^{\cal J}_{\cal M'\cal M}(\beta)\times $ phase for $\vert \cal J\cal M\rangle$).

For practical use, please double check carefully my expressions as you can see the typesetting is involved and prone to small errors.

Comment: Thank you so much!